# Attempting to nest for loops to generate IPv4 Addresses

Tags: loops, rust

I need some help, I am trying to iterate through all ips within an ip range but I am having some issues

I have tried it using loop

```
'pos_1: loop {
        'pos_2: loop {
            'pos_3: loop {
                'pos_4: loop {
                    println!("{}.{}.{}.{}",new_ip[0], new_ip[1], new_ip[2], new_ip[3]);
                    if new_ip[3] == (first_ip[3]+ip_differences[3]) {break 'pos_4;}
                    new_ip[3] += 1;
                }
                if new_ip[2] == (first_ip[2]+ip_differences[2]) {break 'pos_3;}
                new_ip[2] += 1;
            }
            if new_ip[1] == (first_ip[1]+ip_differences[1]) {break 'pos_2;}
            new_ip[1] += 1;
        }
        if new_ip[0] == (first_ip[0]+ip_differences[0]) {break 'pos_1;}
        new_ip[0] += 1;
    }
```

Also with for loop

```
for i in -1..ip_differences[0] {
        for j in -1..ip_differences[1] {
            for k in -1..ip_differences[2] {
                for l in -1..ip_differences[3] {
                    println!("{}.{}.{}.{}", new_ip[0], new_ip[1], new_ip[2], new_ip[3]);
                    if new_ip[3] == (first_ip[3]+ip_differences[3]) {break;}
                    new_ip[3] += 1;

                }
                if new_ip[2] == (first_ip[2]+ip_differences[2]) {break;}

                new_ip[2] += 1;
            }
            if new_ip[1] == (first_ip[1]+ip_differences[1]) {break;}
            new_ip[1] += 1;
        }
        if new_ip[0] == (first_ip[0]+ip_differences[0]) {break;}
        new_ip[0] += 1;
    }
```

Output for the examples above:

```
93.124.176.{...}
93.124.176.248
93.124.176.249
93.124.176.250
93.124.176.251
93.124.176.252
93.124.176.253
93.124.176.254
93.124.176.255
93.124.177.255
93.124.178.255
93.124.179.255
93.124.180.255
93.124.181.255
93.124.182.255
93.124.183.255
```

And also with while loops.
I am using the break keyword as I do not want the value to exceed the upper limit of the range. Typically, I would assume break breaks the current loop, goes to the upper loop (which reinitiates the inner loop) but it feels like when I use break it just completely breaks out the loop and is never used again.

(without break new_ip is incremented every time and you can get 0.0.1234)

Just out of curiosity I tried doing it in java to see if it was my idea that was bad, or my understanding of rust... it is my understanding of rust.

as this does work:

```
for (int i = -1; i < ipDifferences[0]; i++) {
            for (int j = -1; j < ipDifferences[1]; j++) {
                for (int k = -1; k < ipDifferences[2]; k++) {
                    for (int l = -1; l < ipDifferences[3]; l++) {
                        System.out.println(String.format("%s.%s.%s.%s", nIP[0], nIP[1], nIP[2], nIP[3]));
                        if (nIP[3]==(firstIP[3]+ipDifferences[3])) {
                            break;
                        }
                        nIP[3]++;
                    }
                    nIP[3]=firstIP[3];
                    if (nIP[2]==firstIP[2]+ipDifferences[2]) {
                        break;
                    }
                    nIP[2]++;
                }
                nIP[2]=firstIP[2];
                if (nIP[1]==firstIP[1]+ipDifferences[1]) {
                    break;
                }
                nIP[1]++;
            }
            if (nIP[0]==firstIP[0]+ipDifferences[0]) {
                break;
            }
            nIP[0]++;
        }
```

Output for the java adaptation:

```
93.124.175.{...}
...
93.124.176.252
93.124.176.253
93.124.176.254
93.124.176.255
93.124.177.15
93.124.177.16
93.124.177.17
...
93.124.177.255
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=bffefca98ffa049422ed35deecd031d7

Comment: Can you create a reproducible example on the playground?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=bffefca98ffa049422ed35deecd031d7
Mb for not including it

Comment: In Java, you have `nIP[3]=firstIP[3];`, but I don't see an equivalent line in Rust.

Comment: @Jmb wow... i am amazed by my incompetence... thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to set new_ip[3]=first_ip[3];

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

This should help:

```
for _ in 0..3 {
    for _ in 0..3 {
        println!("a");
    }
    println!("b");
}
```

The output of this will be:

```
a,a,a,b,a,a,a,b,a,a,a,b
```

You kind of need to experiment with nested `for` loops a little bit to understand them, but basically the innermost will run as many times as told, and then the next outermost will run, and then the next outermost, and then it will go back to the innermost and run as many times as told, etc.

If we take the sample nested `for` loop and replace the innermost with `5`:

```
for _ in 0..3 {
    for _ in 0..5 {
        println!("a");
    }
    println!("b");
}
```

We get:

```
a,a,a,a,a,b,a,a,a,a,a,b,a,a,a,a,a,b
```

If we change the outermost for loop to a `5`:

```
for _ in 0..5 {
    for _ in 0..3 {
        println!("a");
    }
    println!("b");
}
```

We get this:

```
a,a,a,b,a,a,a,b,a,a,a,b,a,a,a,b,a,a,a,b
```

This should help you understand nested `for` loops much better, because after I threw some numbers around, I definitely felt like I knew what I was doing (until I didn’t again but pretend that won’t happen).

The amount of complexity rapidly increases as you nest more `for` loops, so try to avoid it at all costs, even breaking each `for` loop into a function can help.